# maven can't download jar from nexus

Tags: maven

There are some mistanken

```
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project vinsuan-road-platform-comm: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.vinsuan.road.paltform:vinsuan-road-platform-comm:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.vinsuan4cloud:vinsuan-common-core:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.vinsuan4cloud:vinsuan-common-core:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find com.vinsuan4cloud:vinsuan:pom:1.0.0 in http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9981/repository/sps_group/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sps_group has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
        [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :vinsuan-road-platform-comm`enter code here`
```

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9981 is out company nexus url，So i'am sorry。

then i found some similar problems，their answer are version not match，however，vinsuan-common-core.jar only one version，So i don't know what,i use some operations,such as clean 、compile、install、mvn dependeny:sources,but ide point the mistaken。

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Failure to find com.vinsuan4cloud:vinsuan:pom:1.0.0`. There should be a `pom` file beside the `jar` in the repo in order maven will able to resolve the dependency